# WPF TextBlock ColorAnimation

Tags: c#, wpf

I am totally new with WPF animations, and for the moment I face big problems with this.

I have a `TextBlock` for which, as long as a property to my view model has a specific value, I want to run a `ColorAnimation` to its background color. When the value to my property changes I want the background color for my `TextBlock` to return back to the original one (probably Transparent). Here is what I discovered so far, but it still not working as I described.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding DatabaseTasks.Count, StringFormat= 'Count: {0}'}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent">
                    <TextBlock.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsIdle}" Value="False">
                                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                        <BeginStoryboard>
                                            <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                                <ColorAnimation  RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                                                                 FillBehavior="Stop"
                                                                 From="Red"
                                                                 To="Transparent"
                                                                 By="Blue"
                                                                 Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </BeginStoryboard>
                                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </TextBlock.Style>
                </TextBlock>
```

Can someone fix this?

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:**
The binding works just fine and I tested it using a simple DataTrigger that just changes the background color. My problem is that animation does not stop and return to the orginal color. I am sure I miss something.

Comment: I've tested your data trigger and it worked for me. Most likely you have something wrong with the binding part. Can you check the output window when debugging your code if there is some info about a binding error. Like: System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'IsIdle' property not found on 'object' ''Test' (HashCode=35326503)'. BindingExpression:Path=IsIdle; DataItem='Test' (HashCode=35326503); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name='Foo'); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')

Comment: @Yiğit Yener Thanks for your replay. The binding works ok. There is no error on my Output Window. To me the animation continues even when the value changes.

Comment: Ok. I got it worked. You have to add a <DataTrigger.EnterActions> part and <RemoveStoryboard  BeginStoryboardName="sbBegin"></RemoveStoryboard> tag there. sbBegin is the name of your BeginStoryboard at the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding the `RemoveStoryboard` tag should do it.

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">                            
                    <Style.Triggers>                                 
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsIdle}" Value="False">                                     
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>                                         
                            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="tt" >                                             
                                <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">                                                 
                                    <ColorAnimation  RepeatBehavior="Forever"                                                                  
                                                     FillBehavior="Stop"                                                                  
                                                     From="Red"                                                                  
                                                     To="Transparent"                                                                  
                                                     By="Blue"                                                                  
                                                     Duration="0:0:0.5" />                                             
                                </Storyboard>                                         
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                           </DataTrigger.EnterActions>                                
                         <DataTrigger.ExitActions>       
                            <RemoveStoryboard  BeginStoryboardName="tt"></RemoveStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.ExitActions> 
                    </DataTrigger>                          
                </Style.Triggers>                         
               </Style>
```